# How to create two tabs and on click of that tab data should change in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

[image: UI Image]

How to make these two tabs and change content accordingly by clicking that in react native and also I have to perform checkbox functionality in first tab.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you `React Native Scrollable Tab View`

Installation

```
npm install react-native-scrollable-tab-view --save
```

Usage

```
import {ScrollableTabView, ScrollableTabBar} from '@valdio/react-native-scrollable-tabview';
import { CheckBox,View } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ScrollableTabView
      renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar/>}
    >
      <View tabLabel="GENERAL">
      </View>
      <View tabLabel="MEDIAS">
        //checkbox functionality
        <CheckBox
          value={isSelected}
          onValueChange={setSelection}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollableTabView>
  );

}
```

Further reading
[react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)

Comment: Thank you sir but Inbuilt Checkbox is removed from react-native, so need to make it custom. So by using custom toggle checkbox how can we select multiple data and submit them?